# Sql code to list most common email suffixes from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working with mysql and I want to find the most common email suffixes in my database.

```
Example Dataset:  
bob@gmail.com
billyboy@gmail.com
Kimberly@gmail.com
jimbob@yahoo.com
jimbo@yahoo.com
Bob@hotmail.com
Kyle@aol.com
```

I would want output of:

```
gmail.com - 3
yahoo.com - 2
hotmail.com - 1
aol.com - 1
```

My first instinct is to run this sql command, `"SELECT userEmail FROM email_user_testing"` then run a loop and manipulate the data with PHP, but I have a feeling it'd be much more efficient to use a sql command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
  SUBSTR(userEmail FROM LOCATE('@', userEmail) + 1),
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  email_user_testing
GROUP BY
  SUBSTR(userEmail FROM LOCATE('@', userEmail) + 1)
ORDER BY
  COUNT(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select 
substring_index(usermail,'@',-1) as domain,
count(*) as number
from your_table
group by domain
order by number desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  count(domain) as count
  ,domain 
FROM 
   (
   SELECT  
     REVERSE(
      LEFT(REVERSE(email),LOCATE('@',REVERSE(email)) - 1)
    ) 
   AS domain 
   FROM table
  ) 
  GROUP BY
   domain
  ORDER BY
   count DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I found the most common email domains in my database.

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',-1) AS domain,
    COUNT(*) as count
FROM
    users
GROUP BY
    domain 
ORDER BY
    count desc;

+----------------------------------------------+-------+
| domain                                       | count |
+----------------------------------------------+-------+
| hotmail.com                                  | 51539 |
| gmail.com                                    | 49470 |
| hotmail.co.uk                                | 38872 |
| yahoo.co.uk                                  | 18528 |
| yahoo.com                                    | 18082 |
| live.co.uk                                   |  7662 |
| googlemail.com                               |  5481 |
| btinternet.com                               |  3645 |
| aol.com                                      |  3281 |
| msn.com                                      |  2137 |
| live.com                                     |  2103 |
| ymail.com                                    |  1450 |
| wp.pl                                        |  1290 |
| sky.com                                      |  1226 |
| hotmail.it                                   |  1092 |
| hotmail.fr                                   |  1063 |
...
```